# Which is the correct ISO file to download Ubuntu 13.04 on a laptop with an Intel Core i5 processor?

Tags: installation, live-usb, iso, cpu

The Ubuntu website automatically downloads an ISO file with the -amd64.iso suffix. I see no option to download one for an Intel processor. I don't know if it even matters or if this -amd64.iso is universal for all computers. I have a Lenovo P500 with Windows 8 and I'm trying to create a bootable USB stick. I followed the instructions on http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows and Pen Drive Linux has 2 options for the ISO file download. It has the -amd64.iso and an -i83.iso file. I downloaded the -i83 but I'm not sure if I was supposed to download the other one since the main website only downloads -amd64. Can someone please clarify? Help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMD64 is affixed to the end of the name of the file, because AMD was the first to adopt a realistic 64-bit architecture that was backwards-compatible, therefore, Intel has to **license** the x86-64 instruction set from **AMD**.

In other words, there is no Intel version, and there is no AMD version. As long as you have a processor made after 2006-2008, you have 64-bit support, and should use the 64-bit version of Ubuntu. (Ubuntu *-amd64.iso)

Comment: Oh, ok. So what was the -i83 file I downloaded?

Comment: Doesn't matter, and I can't find any information about it.

Comment: Ok thank you so much. You seem to know all about Ubuntu. Is there a way to message me on here? I'm having trouble making a bootable USB stick to use with W8 because I've read that the Wubi installer that comes with what I downloaded might delete data from preinstalled W8 computers.

Comment: @Rick, there's no way to message people. Windows 8 **broke** Wubi beyond repair, and consequently, it's not included on the 13.04 ISO. To deal with the annoyances caused by windows 8, read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)